# Read byte array byte by byte using C#

Tags: c#

I have a byte array and I want to read this array byte by byte and displayed each byte as integer.

how to do this using C#?

Comment: You're better off writing a single question about what it is you are trying to accomplish rather than making a question for every step you take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the array is called `bytes`:

```
foreach(var b in bytes)
{
    Console.WriteLine((int)b);
}
```

Though, in all fairness, the cast to int is probably unnecessary for display purposes.

Comment: Yep, it is unnecessary. `Console.WriteLine` calls `.ToString()` on it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the C# code I have been writing communicates via TCP/IP with legacy C++ applications. Some codes use a raw packet format where C/C++ structures are passed back and forward.

Example of what the legacy code could look like: 
[Best Practice Mapping a byte array to a structure in C#](https://iodocs.com/net/csharp/best-practice-mapping-byte-array-structure-csharp/)